# Replacing backslashes in golang

Tags: python, regex, go

How can we replace back slashes in golang something similar to we do in python:

```
# python implementation
cleaned_regexp = regexp.replace('\\\\', '%temp%').replace('\\\\', '\\')
```

Transitioning from python to golang and very recently started with development in go so any help will be really great.

Thanks

Comment: Use strings.ReplaceAll (and not a regexp!).

Comment: Your Python code first replaces two backslashes with `%temp%`; the second replacement has no effect. Your Go code first replaces two backslashes with one backslash; the second replacement has no effect. Simply remove one of the replacements in both snippets.

Comment: Aways keep in mind the famous quip from Jamie Zawinski: «Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems». So, in this particular case, do what Volker suggested; do not overengineer: REs do have their application but simple replacement of a fixed substring with another is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by commenters, there is no need to use a regular expression since the string containing two backslash characters requires no special matching. A simpler approach would be to use [`strings.ReplaceAll()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#ReplaceAll).

Note also that using a [raw string literal (between back quotes)](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) makes the code a bit easier to understand since it avoids interpreting the backslash.

```go
s := `foo\\bar`
oldstr := `\\`
newstr := "%temp%"
strings.ReplaceAll(s, oldstr, newstr) // => "foo%temp%bar"
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/yVaZloXAEJ3).